# Inequalities with stochastic Big O

Tags: probability, asymptotics, weak-convergence

I have a very general question related to inequalities containing stochastic big o notation.

> Introduction: consider two sequences of real-valued random variables
>    $\{X_n\}_n$, $\{Y_n\}_n$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega,
>  \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Consider also a function $g:
>  \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $$(*) X_n\geq
>  Y_n-O_p(g(n))$$
>
> We know that $(*)$ is equivalent to  $$(**) X_n\geq Y_n+O_p(g(n))$$

Question: take for example Theorem 5.52 at page 75 of van der Vaart "Asymptotic Theory"; among the sufficient conditions we have $\mathbb{P}_nm_{\hat{\theta}_n}\geq \mathbb{P}m_{\theta_0}-O_p(n^{\frac{\alpha}{2\beta-2\alpha}})$. Is there any reason for stating the theorem using as sufficient condition $\mathbb{P}_nm_{\hat{\theta}_n}\geq \mathbb{P}m_{\theta_0}-O_p(n^{\frac{\alpha}{2\beta-2\alpha}})$ instead of $\mathbb{P}_nm_{\hat{\theta}_n}\geq \mathbb{P}m_{\theta_0}+O_p(n^{\frac{\alpha}{2\beta-2\alpha}})$ ?